# maple evaluate function of variables containing x

Tags: functions, maple

[image: The problem]

Well this is basically the problem.
I want to evaluate a function but the variable x is defined inside a, so for some reason maple doesn't substitute 7 for x.

Comment: I think you should have defined $a$ as a function of $x$. Maple probably thinks the x for f and the x for a are different

Answer (score 2):

```
a := 3*x + 5;

f := unapply(a, x);
```

And then call `f(7);` etc.

In the incorrect way you were trying before you were mixing up the global name `x` with the procedure's formal parameter `x`.

This is a Maple FAQ and the `unapply` command is intended for doing this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

Using substitution works:

```
    |\^/|     Maple 17 (X86 64 LINUX)
._|\|   |/|_. Copyright (c) Maplesoft, a division of Waterloo Maple Inc. 2013
 \  MAPLE  /  All rights reserved. Maple is a trademark of
 <____ ____>  Waterloo Maple Inc.
      |       Type ? for help.
> a := 3*x+5;
                                 a := 3 x + 5

> f := subs(val=a, x -> val);
                               f := x -> 3 x + 5

> f(7);
                                      26
```